# how do I test my implementation of google authenticator?

Tags: c++, windows, testing, implementation, google-authenticator

I have written an implementation of google authenticator as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator

Now my only question is: how can I check whether the 6 digit codes my program generates are correct? I haven't been able to find any web demo for developers at google itself. Elsewhere on the web I found these:

https://2fa.glitch.me/

http://blog.tinisles.com/2011/10/google-authenticator-one-time-password-algorithm-in-javascript/

My codes agree with none of these. The first one may be using a wrong time. I don't know about the second one. Is there such an implementation online that is known to be correct?

My implementation uses the 32 bit unix time as message. I have checked with sources on the web that the time I generate is correct. I have remembered to use big endian. I have checked my hmac_sha1 function and it's correct. The hash generated is 20 byte. As I understand the low order nibble of the last byte is the offset, right? Then the truncated hash is the 4 bytes starting at this offset, interpreted as a bigendian 32 bit integer, albeit with the MSB zeroed. Am I right? Finally you use this modulo 1 million as a 6 digit decimal integer, yes?

The secret key is entered as a base32 string and must be decoded. I have checked that my decoding function is correct.

What can I be doing wrong? Or maybe I'm not doing anything wrong? How to find out? I could open an account with google and configure it to use 2FA and then see if I can log in with my own codes etc, but it's very tedious and I would soon be blocked if my codes are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered an error of mine and with that corrected my codes agree with those here:

https://2fa.glitch.me/

So I can confirm that these codes are correct. The likelihood of his and my codes agreeing if one or both of our implementations contain bugs is practically zero, so that online implementation may be regarded as an authoritative one. Everybody else can check their programs against it.

My error was to treat Unix time as a 32 bit quantity. In this application it must be treated as a 64 bit one (big endian), i.e. 8 bytes starting at the MSB.